# About the use of Poincaré inequality in an open interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral, sobolev-spaces

I have a question about the use of Poincaré inequality. If we consider an open interval $I=(l_0,l_1) \subset \mathbb{R}$ and define the Sobolev space

$$ H_{l_0}^2:=\{u\in H^2(I):u(l_0)=u'(l_0)=0\}.$$

How do I prove using Poincaré inequality that $\|u\|_{L^2(I)}\leq C\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}$ for all $u \in H^2_{l_0}$.

**My attemps:**

Since $u\in H^2(I)$ I have that $u\in H^1(I)$ and I know that  $\|u\|_{L_2(I)}\leq \|u\|_{H^1(I)}$.

Now, using the [Generalized Poincaré Inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1795925/generalized-poincar%C3%A9-inequality-on-h1-proof) I obtain:

$$ \|u\|_{L^2(I)}^2\leq \|u\|_{H^1(I)}^2\leq C\left(\|u'\|_{L^2(I)}^2+\int_{\{l_0,l_1\}}(\gamma u)^2\,d\sigma\right).$$

I think that the term $\int_{\{l_0,l_1\}}(\gamma u)^2\,d\sigma$ dissapears but I don't know how to get to that part.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simpler than that: Recall that in one dimension Sobolev functions of order 1 (you even have order 2) are absolutely continuous and we have that the fundamental theorem of calculus holds. Now for $u\in H^2_{l_0}$ by definition we have
$$
u(t)= u(l_0)+ \int_{l_0}^t u'(s)\, ds=\int_{l_0}^{t} u'(s)\, ds, \qquad l_0\leq t\leq l_1,
$$
so that taking absolute values, and using Cauchy-Schwarz,
$$
|u(t)|\leq (t-l_0)^{1/2}\| u'\|_2.
$$
Now square and integrate over $[l_0,l_1]$ to get
$$
\| u\|_2^2 \leq \| u'\|_2^2 \int_{l_0}^{l_1} (t-t_0)\, dt = \dfrac{(l_1-l_0)^2}{2}\| u'\|_2^2.
$$
This is what you want with $C=(l_1-l_0)/\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, and that seems to be a really good answer to my questions. But, in fact I really need to use Poincaré inequality in the proof. Can you help me to do the proof with this inequality? Also, I think that the inequality that I shown before is not the one I need. Please, help me with this if u can.

Comment: If $u(l_0)\neq 0$, you can rework the above proof in the obvious way to prove a more general version than your generalized Poincare inequality. Issue is, we need this refinement considering only one of the endpoints of your interval in order to conclude what you want due to the definition of $H^2_{l_0}$. If this is not the inequality that you want, I'd suggest making another question in order to avoid confusing edits.

Comment: @CharlesXavier the above arguments show $|u(l_1)|^2 \le \sqrt{l_1-l_0} \|u'\|_{L^2}$. Now use that in the generalized Poincare inequality to get rid of the boundary term on $l_1$. The one for $l_0$ vanishes due to $u(l_0)=0$.